# Deleting files in php directory

Tags: php

```
if(unlink('./'.date('m-d-Y').'/'.$file))
{

    echo "file named $file has been deleted successfully";
}
else
{
echo "file is not deleted";
}
```

I have the code above to delete my files.
However, is it possible to only let it delete files that contain `".5010."`
Can I do something like `"%.5010.%"` or something, also if its more than one file do I need to put it in a while or a foreach loop? Because now it deletes all my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to find the pathnames matching a pattern.

So your code would look something like this,

```
$path="./".date('m-d-Y')."/*".$file."*";
$files = glob($path); // this will return multiple files.
foreach ($files as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```

> **glob()** returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

Comment: With my code it is deleting the "5010" but its also redoing them again, does your code solve this issue as well?

Comment: It will delete files have names 5010 and which has 5010 in it.

Comment: It doesn't delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on file with glob and after use `preg_match` to select files who match a pattern

```
<?php
foreach(glob('path/to/dir/*.*') as $file) {
    if (preg_match('*.5010.*', $file)) {
        unlink($file)
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks fine, @Jasmine22 test this.

Comment: You're missing the delimiters on that `preg_match()` http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php